# git get the branch where the last commit have been done

Tags: git, bash

I'm looking the way to the get the branch where the last commit have be done, now i'm doing something like

```
last_co_branch=$(git branch --sort=-committerdate| head -1| grep -o -e "develop" -e "master")

if [[ "$last_co_branch" == "master" ]]; then

  # stuff ... 
fi 

if [[ "$last_co_branch" == "develop" ]]; then

  # stuff ... 
fi
```

but it's looking weird.

Comment: How would you like to simplify it? What is wrong with this?

Comment: This is not portable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
last_co_branch=$(git for-each-ref --count=1 --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)')
if [[ "$last_co_branch" == "master" ]]; then
  # stuff ... 
fi 
if [[ "$last_co_branch" == "develop" ]]; then
  # stuff ... 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought, it would be shorter :)

Comment: Do you mean something like `git branch -v | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: I'm thinking about something like "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <shortcut-to-last-commit>"